# Emberjs: transitionToRoute in the same route with different model value

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

I have an Ember application composed from 3 routes:

1. `router.route('territory', { path: 'localhost/app/territory/:tid' });`
2. `router.route('aggregator', { path:  localhost/app/territory/:tid:/aggregator/:aid' });`
3. `router.route(territory, { path: 'localhost/app/territory/:tid/aggregator/:aid/item/:iid' });`

the possibles transition are from territory to aggregator, from aggregator to item, and from item to a sub item.
The sub item use the same route (the 3rd), just changing the iID value in the model of route.

I had created an action that allows the user to move into a particular route with some logic and at the end run the command:

```
model={
    tid: "ttt"
    aid: "aaa"
    iid: "iii"
}

destination = 'item'; //the name of item route

controller.transitionToRoute(destination, model);
```

If I'm in the item route and I want to move to an other item, the URL will update, but not the content of the page. Obviously if I refresh the page with the generate URL the content will update.

Where is the problem? in the transition method that is Deprecated, or i have to use something different?

IMPORTANT: I'm using EmberJS - V1.0.0-RC.1

Comment: I'm running into this same issue -- did you manage to figure it out?

Comment: Same problem here. Ever get anywhere with this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ember - Transition to same route with same model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32284939/ember-transition-to-same-route-with-same-model)

Answer (score 0):

Is not a bug is just a normal situation in emberjs because every route have `model` and `setupController`.
The model function is used to retrive asynchronously from WS or Data module the necessary information (is a [RSVP.Promise](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.RSVP.Promise.html)). When is complete the information will be passed to `setupController` function, where will be possible set properties of the controller connected with the view of current route.
Every time that i change the value of path but not the route, only `setupController` will be called.
To conclude, in my case, the problem was just an organisation problem of code.