# Ember - Transition to same route with same model

Tags: ember.js

I have a left tree list, and each item in the list opens same route with different model. What i want is, if i click on the same item again and again, i want the route to load again. I know ember doesn't normally function this way. Are there any tweaks to achieve this?

Update:
Left tree is parent route.On clicking items in left tree, child route is loaded in its outlet.

My left tree will be structured like this,

`item1(link to bodyRoute1 with model1)
item2(link to bodyRoute1 with model2)
item3(link to bodyRoute1 with model3)
item4(link to bodyRoute2 with model1)
...etc`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by doing like this,

I maintain the `currentRouteName` and `currentModelId`(An id to uniquely identify the model) in an object and it is injected in all routes. It gets updated on any transition.

All the transitions from left tree go through a common function, And in that function i check if the forwarding route,modelId is the same as current route,modelId. If so, i change the value of another globally injected property `refreshSameRoute`. This value is observed in the child routes and if it changes `this.refresh()` is called.

Still searching for a better method.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `refresh()` route method [api link](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_refresh), for example:

```
// route
actions: {
  refreshRoute: function() {
    this.refresh();
  }
}

//template
<ul>
  {{#each items as |item|}}
    <li {{action 'refreshRoute'}}>{{item}}</li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

**Update**

> One of the controller property need to be updated from server

So you could use `afterModel` model hook.

From [guides](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.13.0/routing/asynchronous-routing/#toc_beforemodel-and-aftermodel):

The most common reason for this is that if you're transitioning into a route with a dynamic URL segment via `{{link-to}}` or `transitionTo` (as opposed to a transition caused by a URL change), the model for the route you're transitioning into will have already been specified (e.g. `{{#link-to 'article' article}}` or `this.transitionTo('article', article))`, in which case the **model hook won't get called**.

In these cases, you'll need to make use of either the `beforeModel` or **`afterModel` hook to house any logic** while the router is still gathering all of the route's models to perform a transition.

Comment: Left tree is a parent route. Updated the question.

Comment: Could I ask what you definitly mean by "route to load again" with the same model? You want the model to be refreshed from server or may be you want to perform something in model hook? Usually such a behavior could be achieved by modifying `model`, `beforeModel`, `afterModel` and `setupController` hooks. But it depends on what you want exactly.

Comment: Yes, One of the controller property need to be updated from server.

Comment: I guess you didnt understand my requirement. I have the followed the above step, used afterModel to get data from server and everything is completed. If i click the left tree item again, none of the hooks in the route is being called. That is my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

The methods for transitions, like `transitionToRoute` and `replaceRoute`, returns some params, including the `targetName`. When the query params are the same, the `targetName` returns `undefined`. You can check that and do a route refreshing.

```
const queryParams = {<your params>};
const routeName = 'my.route';
const transition = this.transitionToRoute(routeName, { queryParams });
if (transition.targetName !== routeName) {
    const route = getOwner(this).lookup(`route:${routeName}`);
    route.refresh();
}
```